# Saving a file in a different place for linux

Tags: c++, char, filepath

I am trying to save a file somewhere else than the folder of the exe. I have pieced together this unelegant way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    //getting current path of the executable 
    char executable_path[256];
    getcwd(executable_path, 255);


    //unelegant back and forth conversion to add a different location
    string file_loction_as_string;
    file_loction_as_string = executable_path;
    file_loction_as_string += "/output_files/hello_world.txt"; //folder has to exist
    char *file_loction_as_char = const_cast<char*>(file_loction_as_string.c_str());

    // creating, writing, closing file
    ofstream output_file(file_loction_as_char);
    output_file << "hello world!";
    output_file.close();
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? So that the char-string-char* is not necessary.

Also is it possible to create the output folder in the process apart from `mkdir`?

Thank you

Comment: Note that getcwd does not give you the path to the executable. Why the const_cast?

Comment: I had to add it cos putting file_location_as_string right away returns the following error:  no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const std::basic_ofstream<char>&’

Comment: Your `const_cast` is bad. If you use it without knowing why, consider it an error. Either use `const char *file_loction_as_char` without the cast, or pass `file_loction_as_string.c_str()` to your ofstream directly. In C++11 you can pass a string directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of 3 lines of code if you use the following.

```
int main() 
{
    //getting current path of the executable 
    char executable_path[256];
    getcwd(executable_path, 255);

    //unelegant back and forth conversion to add a different location
    string file_loction_as_string = string(executable_path) + "/output_files/hello_world.txt";

    // creating, writing, closing file
    ofstream output_file(file_loction_as_string.c_str());
    output_file << "hello world!";
    output_file.close();
}
```